# Scraping <span> text</span> with BeautifulSoup and urllib

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape **2015** from below HTML:
[image: HTML code]

I use the below code but am only able to scrape "Annee"

```
soup.find('span', {'class':'optionLabel'}).get_text()
```

Can someone please help?

I am a new learner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply try to find its next `span` that holds the text you wanna scrape:

```
soup.find('span',  {'class':'optionLabel'}).find_next('span').get_text()
```

or `css selectors` with `adjacent sibling combinator`:

```
soup.select_one('span.optionLabel + span').get_text()
```

###### Example

```
html='''
<span class="optionLabel"><button>Année</button</span> :
<span>2015</span>'''
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
soup.find('span', {'class':'optionLabel'}).find_next('span').get_text()
```

###### Output

```
2015
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I actually noticed that I have to be more specific. Better if I share the link: https://www.lacentrale.fr/auto-occasion-annonce-87102353714.html                 So basically I need to scrape "2015" and "09/09/2015", but since there are many 'li' and 'ul', I cant scrape exact text. Your help is highly appreaciated.

Comment: Many thanks. I posted a new question, as recommended.